# fullcalendar add constraint when trying to add an external event already exist in the day

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

I am using FullCalendar with Javascript and I would like to drag external events into the calendar with the Draggable API. My problem is that I do bot know how to verify if the event that I would like to add does not exist in one of the days in the calendar.

For Example, I have a list of external events `[Event1, Event2 ...]` and in the calendar, I have in the day `23-12-2020` an event named `'Event1'`. So, I would like to block the user when they try adding `Event1` into the day `23-12-2020` and allow them to add this event where they want.

```
<div id='external-events'>
  <p>
    <strong>Draggable Events</strong>
  </p>

  <div class='fc-event fc-h-event fc-daygrid-event fc-daygrid-block-event'>
    <div class='fc-event-main'>My Event 1</div>
  </div>
  <div class='fc-event fc-h-event fc-daygrid-event fc-daygrid-block-event'>
    <div class='fc-event-main'>My Event 2</div>
  </div>
  <div class='fc-event fc-h-event fc-daygrid-event fc-daygrid-block-event'>
    <div class='fc-event-main'>My Event 3</div>
  </div>
  <div class='fc-event fc-h-event fc-daygrid-event fc-daygrid-block-event'>
    <div class='fc-event-main'>My Event 4</div>
  </div>
  <div class='fc-event fc-h-event fc-daygrid-event fc-daygrid-block-event'>
    <div class='fc-event-main'>My Event 5</div>
  </div>

  <p>
    <input type='checkbox' id='drop-remove' />
    <label for='drop-remove'>remove after drop</label>
  </p>
</div>

<div id='calendar-container'>
  <div id='calendar'></div>
</div>
```

```
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
}

#external-events {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 2;
  top: 20px;
  left: 20px;
  width: 150px;
  padding: 0 10px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background: #eee;
}

#external-events .fc-event {
  cursor: move;
  margin: 3px 0;
}

#calendar-container {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  margin-left: 200px;
}

#calendar {
  max-width: 1100px;
  margin: 20px auto;
}
```

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var Calendar = FullCalendar.Calendar;
  var Draggable = FullCalendar.Draggable;

  var containerEl = document.getElementById('external-events');
  var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
  var checkbox = document.getElementById('drop-remove');

  // initialize the external events
  // -----------------------------------------------------------------

  new Draggable(containerEl, {
    itemSelector: '.fc-event',
    eventData: function(eventEl) {
      return {
        title: eventEl.innerText
      };
    }
  });

  // initialize the calendar
  // -----------------------------------------------------------------

  var calendar = new Calendar(calendarEl, {
    headerToolbar: {
      left: 'prev,next today',
      center: 'title',
      right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay'
    },
    editable: true,
    droppable: true, // this allows things to be dropped onto the calendar
    drop: function(info) {
      // is the "remove after drop" checkbox checked?
      if (checkbox.checked) {
        // if so, remove the element from the "Draggable Events" list
        info.draggedEl.parentNode.removeChild(info.draggedEl);
      }
    }
  });

  calendar.render();
});

 function getEvents(date){
        all_events.forEach(function(entry) {
            if (entry['start'] == date.format()){
                alert(entry['title']);}
            else if (entry['start'] <= date.format() && entry['end'] >= date.format()){
                alert(entry['title']);}
         });
    
    }
```

Comment: Look into https://fullcalendar.io/docs/eventReceive . In this callback you can look at the incoming event, which would then enable you to compare it with the existing events in your calendar, to see if you want to allow it or not. If you don't want to allow it, there's a callback function supplied which you can call in order to cancel adding the event.